# Cannot read property 'username' of undefined Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im trying to create a list of Profile objects and then display certain elements of each object in the list. I have created a public interface called Profile, imported it into my component, and then I create a new object of type Profile and assign `id, username, and profilepic`.

The problem is that while I am able to setup and assign the object to my array, my `*ngFor` statement doesn't seem to see the attributes `id,username, or profilepic`. I find this weird because if I call `console.log(curP.username);`, I get the correct username in the console. Have I defined something incorrectly? `console.log(this.displayActiverUser);` also returns the correct list of users with `id,username,profilepic`.

Interface:

```
export interface Profile {
    id: any;
    username: any;
    profilePic: any;
}
```

Component:

```
displayActiveUser = new Array<Profile>(10); //this is the array displayed as users
activeUserArray = new Array(10);

for (var n = 0; n < numAvalAcct; n++){
    let curP: Profile = {id: parseInt(this.activeUserArray[n][1]),username: this.activeUserArray[n][0], profilePic: "testurl"};
          console.log("usernm", curP.username);
          this.displayActiveUser[n] = curP;
        }
```

HTML *ngFor (The error appears on line where `{{profile.username}}`

```
<div class="list-group">
                <a *ngFor="let profile of displayActiveUser" (click)="followedNewUser(profile)" href="" target="popup"  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                    <img src="" class="rounded-circle" alt="profile picture" width="25" height="25"> {{profile.username}} 
                </a>
</div>
```

Output for `console.log(this.displayActiverUser);`

```
0: {id: 135, username: "adamhaddad4", profilePic: "testurl"}
1: {id: 136, username: "ian.mccleary", profilePic: "testUrl"}
2: {id: 1, username: "dddd", profilePic: "testurl"}
3: {id: 134, username: "timtim1", profilePic: "testUrl"}
```

EDIT: The full error is:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at FollowForFollowComponent_a_6_Template (follow-for-follow.component.html:8)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7329)
    at refreshView (core.js:7198)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8289)
    at refreshView (core.js:7222)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8335)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6991)
    at refreshView (core.js:7248)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8289)
    at refreshView (core.js:7222)
```

Comment: Could you share your error message? @Ian McCleary

Comment: @Muthupriya ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
    at FollowForFollowComponent_a_6_Template (follow-for-follow.component.html:8)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7329)
    at refreshView (core.js:7198)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8289)
    at refreshView (core.js:7222)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8335)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6991)
    at refreshView (core.js:7248)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8289)
    at refreshView (core.js:7222)

Comment: Hard to know without seeing more of the code, but I would wager the view is executing before you copied elements into the `displayActiveUser` array. You initialized it as an array of 10 elements, so the `ngFor` is executing, but each item is `undefined` because they weren't copied over yet.

Comment: You created array with 10 empty slots, and filled in only 4.

Comment: You were right! I just figured it out at the same time....by initializing the list with 10 elements, my view was already attempting to display the list before my values were assigned. I fixed it by using  `.push()` instead of `this.displayActiveUser[n] = curP;`. If you want to make your comment into an answer, feel free. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`displayActiveUser = new Array<Profile>(10);` created an array with 10 undefineds in it.

What you want to do is use a map function to transform your source to the displayed data. We don't really reach for the for loop in modern JavaScript, people tend to stick to functions like map and filter.

```
this.displayActiveUser = this.activeUserArray.map(user => transformUser(user));
```

where transformUser is a function that does the mapping of one object to the other

Answer (score 0):

```
displayActiveUser = new Array<Profile>(10);
```

Initializes array with 10 empty slots.

See [Array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array).

The debug output shows that you filled only 4 slots, the others are still empty.

Answer (score -1):

Create a class that implements the interface:

```js
export interface ProfileInterface {
  id: any;
  username: any;
  profilePic: any;
}

export class Profile implements ProfileInterface {
  id = null;
  username = '';
  profilePic = null;
}
```

I have tested the code. Enjoy coding!